# How do I redirect a directory's default file with IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect

I want the default document in a folder to redirect to another URL but I still want other files in the same directory to be served normally. How can I do this in IIS 7? For example:

```
my-site.com/              => redirects to http://example.com
my-site.com/default.aspx  => redirects to http://example.com
my-site.com/foo.aspx      => served normally
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create default.aspx and redirect it to another page, the other pages should still work.

In IIS Manager, right click the default.aspx page, select properties, select the radio button for A redirection to a URL.  Enter the redirection URL and click OK.

In IIS 7, drill down to the page in Content view, then when you click the page select Switch to Features View and select HTTP redirect.

Comment: Are these instructions for IIS 7? I don't see `Properties` when I go into Content View and right click the file.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. I tried that and IIS is redirecting for `/default.aspx` but not `/`. Is it supposed to redirect for both?

Comment: if you redirect / I believe it will not allow you to get inside the directory.  The default file should be sufficient.